# What does this notation involving greater than sign mean?

Tags: calculus, notation

Basically it says that $$|x|>1,2n|a_{n-1}|,\ldots,2n|a_0|$$

Does this mean that $$|x|>\max(1,2n|a_{n-1}|,\ldots,2n|a_0|)$$

It seems to be essential when proving that polynomial whose degree (namely $n$) is odd has a root.

Reference: Spivak Calculus,chapter 7 page 111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You guessed correctly, it means that $|x|>1\land x>2n|a_{n-1}| \land \ldots \land x>2n|a_0|.$

Or equivalently, as you suggested, $|x|>\max(1,2n|a_{n-1}|,\ldots,2n|a_0|)$.

Comment: Comment, down voter?

Comment: Mathematical hipsters again. Don't mind, [throw the downvotes on the ground!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)#Half_adder).